# How to get File Path of File Uploaded Through Custom Option

Tags: custom-options

I'm working with a function that runs immediately after a user submits an order to his/her Magento shopping cart, and I'm trying to get the URL for the file the user has just uploaded, so that I can manipulate it before the order is officially submitted.

I'm getting the quote data correct, and when I output the object with print_r, I can SEE where the URL is in the object data, but I can't write the code to actually pull that specifically. Here's a snippet of my function:

```
    <?php
        class Image_Processor_Model_Observer {
          public function autoMetaDescription(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

          $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
          $options = $checkout->getProductOptions();
          $sales_quote = $options->sales_quote;

          print "<pre>";
          print_r($checkout);
          print "</pre>";

         die();
        }
      }
    ?>
```

And here's a snippet of the output I'd like to access:

```
[option_3] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Option Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [_item:protected] => Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                    [_product:protected] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
                                                                    [_eventObject:protected] => object
                                                                    [_resourceName:protected] => sales/quote_item_option
                                                                    [_resource:protected] => 
                                                                    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => sales/quote_item_option_collection
                                                                    [_cacheTag:protected] => 
                                                                    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
                                                                    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
                                                                    [_data:protected] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [product_id] => 3
                                                                            [product] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product Object
 *RECURSION*
                                                                            [code] => option_3
                                                                            [value] => a:9:{s:4:"type";s:24:"application/octet-stream";s:5:"title";s:19:"EatingBreakfast.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"\media\custom_options\quote\E\a\9884fbc76ede5ddb9ef991b83c17f8ae.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"\media\custom_options\order\E\a\9884fbc76ede5ddb9ef991b83c17f8ae.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:93:"D:\Our Files\Web\lifewall\media\custom_options\quote\E\a\9884fbc76ede5ddb9ef991b83c17f8ae.jpg";s:4:"size";s:7:"8050795";s:5:"width";i:3000;s:6:"height";i:3997;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"9884fbc76ede5ddb9ef9";}
                                                                            [item_id] => 
                                                                        )

                                                                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
                                                                    [_origData:protected] => 
                                                                    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                                                                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                                                                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                        )

                                                                )
```

I hope that's all clear. I just need the .jpg path you see in the 'value' part of the output. Any ideas how to pull that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go `$uploadedImage = json_decode($checkout->getValue());` to decode the submitted values. You then should be able to then use `$path = $uploadedImage->fullpath` to get the full path of the image which in your example is `D:\Our Files\Web\lifewall\media\custom_options\quote\E\a\9884fbc76ede5ddb9ef991b83c17f8ae.jpg` or you could use `$url= $uploadedImage->quote_path` to get the url `\media\custom_options\quote\E\a\9884fbc76ede5ddb9ef991b83c17f8ae.jpg` and then use `$fullUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $url`

Comment: Hi, rob3000 -- Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I'm using this:


          ``$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
          $uploadedImage = json_decode($quote->getValue());
          $path = $uploadedImage->fullpath;
          $url= $uploadedImage->quote_path;
          $fullUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $url;``
`
And I'm not able to output any value from $url or $path, even though the values are in that big print_r() output of $quote. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you print_r `$uploadedImage` is anything in there?

Comment: If do `print_r($uploadedImage)`, the number '1' is the only thing that's outputted to the screen.

Comment: can you `print_r($quote->getData())`;

Comment: Yes, I can print that, but all I get for output is this: 

`Array ( [store_id] => 1 [is_checkout_cart] => 1 [remote_ip] => 127.0.0.1 [x_forwarded_for] => ) 1`

Thanks for the continued help, by the way!